# using Material-UI with create-react-app (react 16)

Tags: material-ui, create-react-app

CRA now uses React 17 default and it is advised that we use an older version of CRA that uses R16 whilst MUI5 is being developed. Can someone advise me how they download an older version of CRA? I have tried `npx create-react-app client --typescript --scripts-version react-scripts@3.4.4` and I get `Error: Cannot find module 'cra-template'`. I know this is strictly a CRA question but I thought someone that uses MUI might already have some experience with this problem.

Comment: use `--template typescript`, not `--typescript`

Comment: I tried that, I get the same error `Error: Cannot find module 'cra-template-typescript'`

Comment: `--typescript` was the tag used before CRA version 4

Comment: you should be able to use MUI 4 with React 17, does it not work for you?

Comment: Does using the last 3.0 version work? `--scripts-version "react-scripts@<4.0"`

Comment: when I try and install it using default CRA I get: 

`
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
`

Comment: ...--scripts-version "react-scripts@<4.0":
`Error: Cannot find module 'cra-template-typescript'`

Comment: Have you changed `registry` settings from `npm config` by any chance? It looks like npm can't resolve anything. Can you even install any package at all? try `npm install lodash`

Comment: Because I know for a fact that `cra-template-typescript` exists. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-template-typescript

Comment: yeah, I think your right. I just reinstalled node via nvm and now it works, it installs MUI on the default CRA and just prints the following warning `npm WARN @material-ui/utils@4.10.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.` thanks for your help.